# Updated code: Fragment ArrayList of objects not populated on first run

Tags: android-fragments, arraylist

When running the code the ArrayList ArrayOfCategories1 is empty. When navigating to another fragment and back the ArrayList gets populated. I would like to get it populated the first time. Help would be appreciated as I am quite new to Android.

```
public class TabFragmentOne extends Fragment {

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

private static ArrayList<CategoryData> ArrayOfCategories = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<CategoryData> ArrayOfCategories2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<CategoryData> ArrayOfCategories3 = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String ARG_EXAMPLE = "this_is_a_constant";
private String example_data;

public TabFragmentOne() {

}

public static TabFragmentOne newInstance(String example_argument) {
    TabFragmentOne tabFragmentOne = new TabFragmentOne();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_EXAMPLE, example_argument);
    args.putParcelableArrayList("Categories", ArrayOfCategories2);
    String myMessage = "This is working!";
    args.putString("message", myMessage );
    tabFragmentOne.setArguments(args);
    return tabFragmentOne;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


// references to images
int[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.aardappelen, R.drawable.bier,
        R.drawable.borrelhapjes, R.drawable.broodbeleg_hartig,
        R.drawable.broodbeleg_zoet, R.drawable.dessert,
        R.drawable.eieren, R.drawable.frisdranken,
        R.drawable.fruitsappen, R.drawable.koekjes,
        R.drawable.koffie, R.drawable.limonade,
        R.drawable.pasta, R.drawable.rijst,
        R.drawable.sauzen, R.drawable.vis,
        R.drawable.vlees, R.drawable.wasmiddel,
        R.drawable.wijn_rood, R.drawable.wijn_wit
};

ArrayList<String> mCategories2 = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String Frank = getArguments().getString("message");
    ArrayOfCategories2 = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("Categories");
    System.out.println("Lukt dit1? " + ArrayOfCategories2.size());
    System.out.println("Lukt dit2? " + Frank);

    // Creating the actual gridview
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_collection_view, container, false);

    if (ArrayOfCategories2.isEmpty()) {
        return view;

    } else {

        System.out.println("New: " + ArrayOfCategories2.size());

        ListAdapter imageAdapterCollectionViewCategories = new ImageAdapterCollectionViewCategories(getActivity(), mThumbIds, ArrayOfCategories2);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapterCollectionViewCategories);

        //Click item in gridview
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(TabFragmentOne.this.getActivity(), ProductListActivity.class);
                // pass the item information
                intent.putExtra("categoryName", position);
                System.out.print("Test??:" + position + ":test??");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

        return view;

    }



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Getting the Firebase Category Data
    Firebase mRef;

    mRef = new Firebase("x");

    mRef.child("categories").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            System.out.println("There are again " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " categories");

            ArrayOfCategories2.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot categorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                CategoryData category = categorySnapshot.getValue(CategoryData.class);
                ArrayOfCategories2.add(category);
                System.out.println("Categories?: " + ArrayOfCategories2.size());

            }
            System.out.println("Check3: " + ArrayOfCategories2.get(1).getProductCategory());

            class CategoryComparator implements Comparator<CategoryData> {
                public int compare(CategoryData left, CategoryData right) {

                    return left.getProductCategory().compareTo(right.getProductCategory());
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(ArrayOfCategories2, new CategoryComparator());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.d("MyTag2", "Something went wrong!!");
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
}
```

TabBarActivty:

```
public class TabBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Firebase mRef;

ArrayList<ProductData> ArrayOfProducts = new ArrayList<ProductData>();
ArrayList<ProductData> SectionedArrayOfProducts = new ArrayList<ProductData>();
public static ArrayList<CategoryData> ArrayOfCategories = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<SubCategoryData> ArrayOfSubCategories = new ArrayList<SubCategoryData>();

public static ArrayList<String> ArrayOfCategoriesStrings = new ArrayList<>();

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private int[] tabIcons = {R.drawable.ic_products, R.drawable.ic_lists, R.drawable.ic_selections, R.drawable.ic_info, R.drawable.ic_user};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mRef = new Firebase("x");

    mRef.child("products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("There are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " products");
            for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                ProductData product = productSnapshot.getValue(ProductData.class);
                ArrayOfProducts.add(product);
            }

            class ProductComparator implements Comparator<ProductData> {
                public int compare(ProductData left, ProductData right) {
                    if (right.getProductCategory().equals(left.getProductCategory())) {
                        if (left.getProductSubCategory().equals(right.getProductSubCategory())) {
                            return left.getRecalculatedMetricsPricePerUnit().compareTo(right.getRecalculatedMetricsPricePerUnit());
                        }
                        return left.getProductSubCategory().compareTo(right.getProductSubCategory());
                    }
                    return left.getProductCategory().compareTo(right.getProductCategory());
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(ArrayOfProducts, new ProductComparator());

            for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfProducts.size(); i++) {

                String productName = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductName();
                Double productPrice = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductPrice();
                String productCategory = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductCategory();
                String productSubCategory = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductSubCategory();
                Double productCount = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductCount();
                Double productUnits = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductUnits();
                String productUnitType = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductUnitType();
                Double pricePerUnit = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getPricePerUnit();
                Double recalculatedMetricUnit = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getRecalculatedMetricUnit();
                Double recalculatedMetricsPricePerUnit = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getRecalculatedMetricsPricePerUnit();
                String supermarketName = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getSupermarketName();
                String updatedby = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getUpdatedby();
                String dateLastUpdate = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getDateLastUpdate();
                Double rating = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getRating();
                Double ratingWeight = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getRatingWeight();
                String ratingDate = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getRatingDate();
                String key = ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getKey();

                if (i == 0) {
                    // Create a ProductData object to store the SubCategorySection
                    ProductData productData = new ProductData("SubCategorySectionHeader", null, null, (ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductSubCategory()), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                    SectionedArrayOfProducts.add(productData);
                } else if (!ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductSubCategory().equals(ArrayOfProducts.get(i - 1).getProductSubCategory())) {
                    ProductData productData = new ProductData("SubCategorySectionHeader", null, null, (ArrayOfProducts.get(i).getProductSubCategory()), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                    SectionedArrayOfProducts.add(productData);
                    System.out.println(productData.getProductName() + " " + productData.getProductSubCategory());
                }

                // Create a ProductData object to store details
                ProductData productData = ArrayOfProducts.get(i);
                SectionedArrayOfProducts.add(productData);

                System.out.println(SectionedArrayOfProducts.size());
            }
            System.out.println(SectionedArrayOfProducts.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.d("MyTag2", "Something went wrong!!");
        }

    });

    mRef.child("categories").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("There are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " categories");
            for (DataSnapshot categorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                CategoryData category = categorySnapshot.getValue(CategoryData.class);
                ArrayOfCategories.add(category);
            }
            System.out.print("Check5: " + ArrayOfCategories.size());
            System.out.println(ArrayOfCategories);


            class CategoryComparator implements Comparator<CategoryData>
            {
                public int compare(CategoryData left, CategoryData right) {

                    return left.getProductCategory().compareTo(right.getProductCategory());
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(ArrayOfCategories, new CategoryComparator());

            System.out.print("Check6: " + ArrayOfCategoriesStrings.size());
            Log.d("MyTag", "Oke!");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.d("MyTag2", "Something went wrong!!");
        }

    });

    mRef.child("subcategories").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("There are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " subcategories");
            for (DataSnapshot subcategorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                SubCategoryData subcategory = subcategorySnapshot.getValue(SubCategoryData.class);
                ArrayOfSubCategories.add(subcategory);
            }

            class SubCategoryComparator implements Comparator<SubCategoryData> {
                public int compare(SubCategoryData left, SubCategoryData right) {

                    return left.getProductSubCategory().compareTo(right.getProductSubCategory());
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(ArrayOfSubCategories, new SubCategoryComparator());


            System.out.println(ArrayOfSubCategories.get(1).getProductCategory());
            Log.d("MyTag", "Oke!");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.d("MyTag2", "Something went wrong!!");
        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(TabFragmentOne.newInstance("this data is for fragment 1"), "products", ArrayOfCategories);
    adapter.addFragment(TabFragmentTwo.newInstance("this data is for fragment 2"), "lists", ArrayOfCategories);
    adapter.addFragment(TabFragmentThree.newInstance("this data is for fragment 3"), "selections", ArrayOfCategories);
    adapter.addFragment(TabFragmentFour.newInstance("this data is for fragment 4"), "info", ArrayOfCategories);
    adapter.addFragment(TabFragmentFive.newInstance("this data is for fragment 5"), "user", ArrayOfCategories);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


}

}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mFragmentListTitles = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<CategoryData> categoryDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}


public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title, ArrayList<CategoryData> arrayOfCategories){
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentListTitles.add(title);
    categoryDataArrayList = arrayOfCategories;
}

@Override public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

     return mFragmentListTitles.get(position);

}
}
```

Comment: did you use FragmentStatePagerAdapter for tab??

Comment: I am using FragmentPagerAdapter. Should I use  FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: Change to FragmentStatePagerAdapter did not matter. ArrayList still starts empty and only populates when changing to other fragment and back.

Comment: Move FireBase query mRef.child("categories").addValueEventListener to method onActivityCreated of Fragment.

Comment: I have tried that and still have the same result. I have put an updated version of my code above. Any ideas on how I can get the array with data before the Fragment is created?